# How to compare dates in solr?

Tags: solr

My schema have this two filed

```
<field name="startDate" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="endDate" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

I need to search for the documents where "current time" in between start or end date.

What will be the query?

Answer (score 3):

Cited from https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax

If you use the Solr "DateField" type, any queries on those fields (typically range queries) should use either the Complete ISO 8601 Date syntax that field supports, or the DateMath Syntax to get relative dates. Examples:

```
timestamp:[* TO NOW]
createdate:[1976-03-06T23:59:59.999Z TO *]
createdate:[1995-12-31T23:59:59.999Z TO 2007-03-06T00:00:00Z]
pubdate:[NOW-1YEAR/DAY TO NOW/DAY+1DAY]
createdate:[1976-03-06T23:59:59.999Z TO 1976-03-06T23:59:59.999Z+1YEAR]
createdate:[1976-03-06T23:59:59.999Z/YEAR TO 1976-03-06T23:59:59.999Z]
```

Answer (score 2):

A query string, without escaping for clarity, might look like this (using lucene query parser syntax):

```
?q=startDate:[* TO NOW]&endDate:[NOW TO *]
```